# Cocos2dx - C++ How to add child to a Sprite without stacking them on top of each other

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, sprite

I'm new to **Cocos2dx** and I'm trying to create a betting game named "Shake the disk". So basically, everytime a player put his bet in a gate, I want to show a chip representing that the player has put a bet on that gate. However, using `addChild()` to that gate only works for the first time. In the picture shown below, I first add a red chip to the gate and then I add another green chip to that gate.

However, it appears to me that the green chip was drawn exactly on top of the red chip. I am trying to make two chips appear next to each other so that the player can see that they have put 1 red chip and 1 green chip in that gate.

Thanks for helping me and have a good day folks.

[image: Gatebet.png]

Answer (score 1):

```
cocos2d::MenuItem *menuItemWithImage01 = cocos2d::MenuItemImage::create("unselected_image01_filename.png", "selected_image_filename.png", CC_CALLBACK_1(Layer::Function, this));
cocos2d::MenuItem *menuItemWithImage02 = cocos2d::MenuItemImage::create("unselected_image02_filename.png", "selected_image_filename.png", CC_CALLBACK_1(Layer::Function, this));    
auto menu = new cocos2d::Menu(menuItemWithImage01 ,menuItemWithImage02 , NULL);
menu->alignItemsVertically();
this->addChild(menu);
```

This is untested but you could create menu items using images, then add them to the menu, and align the menu items horizontally/vertically as needed.

So in your case just add the menu with all of the chips to the gate and set them visible as they are activated?

Answer (score 0):

You need to offset the position of each sprite you add a little so that they don't fully cover over each other.

Comment: Thanks for your help @PWiggin, I thought about this too and I have already used that approach. However, I wonder if there is any faster way available to deal with this problem